# How to make NCrunch use specific appsettings.json file?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-3.1, ncrunch

There are some API tests in my solution that require setting from `appsettings.json` file. Local environment differs from DEV/PROD. Because of that I have main `appsettings.json` config and additional `appsettings.Development.json` with some settings specific for dev machine.

NCrunch was working fine grabbing settings from the Development config file until new configs were added:

```
appsettings.json
    appsettings.Development.json
    appsettings.Local.json
    appsettings.Production.json
```

I updated `launchSettings.json` file to use Local config. It works fine when I run it from VS, but NCrunch still uses Development. Is there any way to make it use Local?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tried this, but it should get you close.

1. In Visual Studio, go to Extensions->NCrunch->Configuration
2. Select your-project - Shared Settings (or other scope, whatever you prefer)
3. In the bottom pane in the 'General' expander, select 'Custom environment variables'.
4. Add a key / value as ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT and Development.

Comment: Yep! it works! I was looking for such setting on solution/project level so that I could commit it to the repo. The setting you mentioned is in the root General Settings. Anyway, there is no need to change it often, so I think it's ok to set it manually. Thanks Ryan!